# Creating SQL Server Database Users Dynamically from User Input

Tags: .net, security, sql-server, authentication, vb.net

## The Application

I have an application in testing that runs off of an MS SQL Server database. The app allows users to authenticate using Windows authentication (that is, using the Windows username the user is currently logged in with), but the need was discovered for the app to a have a built-in, independent method of authentication.

Rather than handle the delicate task of storing usernames and passwords in the database- and considering that the database is the thing that needs securing anyway, so keeping the credentials there would defeat the purpose- I came up with the following solution:

Use the built-in [users](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-user?view=sql-server-ver15) functionality in SQL Server to store the users for my application.

## The Code

To this end, I configured the database to be [partially contained](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/contained-databases?view=sql-server-ver15), so database users can be used without having to link them to a server-level login.

I then created the following class:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Module SqlServerAuthenticator

    Public Sub CreateUser(cmd As SqlCommand, UserName As String, Password As String, UserRole As String)
        UserName = QuoteUserName(cmd, UserName)
        Password = QuotePassword(cmd, Password)
        cmd.CommandText = $"CREATE USER {UserName} WITH PASSWORD = {Password}"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If Not UserRole.IsNullOrEmpty Then
            cmd.CommandText = $"ALTER ROLE {UserRole} ADD MEMBER {UserName}"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub DropUser(cmd As SqlCommand, UserName As String)
        UserName = QuoteUserName(cmd, UserName)
        cmd.CommandText = $"DROP USER {UserName}"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Sub

    Public Sub RenameUser(cmd As SqlCommand, CurrentUserName As String, NewUserName As String)
        CurrentUserName = QuoteUserName(cmd, CurrentUserName)
        NewUserName = QuoteUserName(cmd, NewUserName)
        cmd.CommandText = $"ALTER USER {CurrentUserName} WITH NAME = {NewUserName}"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetUserPassword(cmd As SqlCommand, UserName As String, Password As String)
        UserName = QuoteUserName(cmd, UserName)
        Password = QuotePassword(cmd, Password)
        cmd.CommandText = $"ALTER USER {UserName} WITH PASSWORD = {Password}"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Sub

    Public Function ValidateUserName(UserName As String) As Boolean
        If UserName.IsNullOrWhileSpace Then Return False
        If UserName.IndexOfAny(IllegalCharacters) > -1 Then Return False
        If ReservedNames.Contains(UserName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then Return False
        Return True
    End Function

    Private Function QuoteUserName(cmd As SqlCommand, UserName As String) As String
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT QUOTENAME(@UserName)"
        Dim param = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UserName)
        UserName = cmd.ExecuteScalar
        cmd.Parameters.Remove(param)
        Return UserName
    End Function

    Private Function QuotePassword(cmd As SqlCommand, Password As String) As String
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT QUOTENAME(@Password, '''')"
        Dim param = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password)
        Password = cmd.ExecuteScalar
        cmd.Parameters.Remove(param)
        Return Password
    End Function

    Public ReadOnly IllegalCharacters() As Char = "\/*%_^#@[](){};"

    Public ReadOnly ReservedNames() As String = {"sa",
                                                 "public",
                                                 "sa",
                                                 "public",
                                                 "sysadmin",
                                                 "securityadmin",
                                                 "serveradmin",
                                                 "setupadmin",
                                                 "processadmin",
                                                 "diskadmin",
                                                 "dbcreator",
                                                 "bulkadmin",
                                                 "ADD",
                                                 "ALL",
                                                 "ALTER",
                                                 "AND",
                                                 "ANY",
                                                 "AS",
                                                 "ASC",
                                                 "AUTHORIZATION",
                                                 "BACKUP",
                                                 "BEGIN",
                                                 "BETWEEN",
                                                 "BREAK",
                                                 "BROWSE",
                                                 "BULK",
                                                 "BY",
                                                 "CASCADE",
                                                 "CASE",
                                                 "CHECK",
                                                 "CHECKPOINT",
                                                 "CLOSE",
                                                 "CLUSTERED",
                                                 "COALESCE",
                                                 "COLLATE",
                                                 "COLUMN",
                                                 "COMMIT",
                                                 "COMPUTE",
                                                 "CONSTRAINT",
                                                 "CONTAINS",
                                                 "CONTAINSTABLE",
                                                 "CONTINUE",
                                                 "CONVERT",
                                                 "CREATE",
                                                 "CROSS",
                                                 "CURRENT",
                                                 "CURRENT_DATE",
                                                 "CURRENT_TIME",
                                                 "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP",
                                                 "CURRENT_USER",
                                                 "CURSOR",
                                                 "DATABASE",
                                                 "DBCC",
                                                 "DEALLOCATE",
                                                 "DECLARE",
                                                 "DEFAULT",
                                                 "DELETE",
                                                 "DENY",
                                                 "DESC",
                                                 "DISK",
                                                 "DISTINCT",
                                                 "DISTRIBUTED",
                                                 "DOUBLE",
                                                 "DROP",
                                                 "DUMP",
                                                 "ELSE",
                                                 "END",
                                                 "ERRLVL",
                                                 "ESCAPE",
                                                 "EXCEPT",
                                                 "EXEC",
                                                 "EXECUTE",
                                                 "EXISTS",
                                                 "EXIT",
                                                 "EXTERNAL",
                                                 "FETCH",
                                                 "FILE",
                                                 "FILLFACTOR",
                                                 "FOR",
                                                 "FOREIGN",
                                                 "FREETEXT",
                                                 "FREETEXTTABLE",
                                                 "FROM",
                                                 "FULL",
                                                 "FUNCTION",
                                                 "GOTO",
                                                 "GRANT",
                                                 "GROUP",
                                                 "HAVING",
                                                 "HOLDLOCK",
                                                 "IDENTITY",
                                                 "IDENTITY_INSERT",
                                                 "IDENTITYCOL",
                                                 "IF",
                                                 "IN",
                                                 "INDEX",
                                                 "INNER",
                                                 "INSERT",
                                                 "INTERSECT",
                                                 "INTO",
                                                 "IS",
                                                 "JOIN",
                                                 "KEY",
                                                 "KILL",
                                                 "LEFT",
                                                 "LIKE",
                                                 "LINENO",
                                                 "LOAD",
                                                 "MERGE",
                                                 "NATIONAL",
                                                 "NOCHECK",
                                                 "NONCLUSTERED",
                                                 "NOT",
                                                 "NULL",
                                                 "NULLIF",
                                                 "OF",
                                                 "OFF",
                                                 "OFFSETS",
                                                 "ON",
                                                 "OPEN",
                                                 "OPENDATASOURCE",
                                                 "OPENQUERY",
                                                 "OPENROWSET",
                                                 "OPENXML",
                                                 "OPTION",
                                                 "OR",
                                                 "ORDER",
                                                 "OUTER",
                                                 "OVER",
                                                 "PERCENT",
                                                 "PIVOT",
                                                 "PLAN",
                                                 "PRECISION",
                                                 "PRIMARY",
                                                 "PRINT",
                                                 "PROC",
                                                 "PROCEDURE",
                                                 "PUBLIC",
                                                 "RAISERROR",
                                                 "READ",
                                                 "READTEXT",
                                                 "RECONFIGURE",
                                                 "REFERENCES",
                                                 "REPLICATION",
                                                 "RESTORE",
                                                 "RESTRICT",
                                                 "RETURN",
                                                 "REVERT",
                                                 "REVOKE",
                                                 "RIGHT",
                                                 "ROLLBACK",
                                                 "ROWCOUNT",
                                                 "ROWGUIDCOL",
                                                 "RULE",
                                                 "SAVE",
                                                 "SCHEMA",
                                                 "SECURITYAUDIT",
                                                 "SELECT",
                                                 "SEMANTICKEYPHRASETABLE",
                                                 "SEMANTICSIMILARITYDETAILSTABLE",
                                                 "SEMANTICSIMILARITYTABLE",
                                                 "SESSION_USER",
                                                 "SET",
                                                 "SETUSER",
                                                 "SHUTDOWN",
                                                 "SOME",
                                                 "STATISTICS",
                                                 "SYSTEM_USER",
                                                 "TABLE",
                                                 "TABLESAMPLE",
                                                 "TEXTSIZE",
                                                 "THEN",
                                                 "TO",
                                                 "TOP",
                                                 "TRAN",
                                                 "TRANSACTION",
                                                 "TRIGGER",
                                                 "TRUNCATE",
                                                 "TRY_CONVERT",
                                                 "TSEQUAL",
                                                 "UNION",
                                                 "UNIQUE",
                                                 "UNPIVOT",
                                                 "UPDATE",
                                                 "UPDATETEXT",
                                                 "USE",
                                                 "USER",
                                                 "VALUES",
                                                 "VARYING",
                                                 "VIEW",
                                                 "WAITFOR",
                                                 "WHEN",
                                                 "WHERE",
                                                 "WHILE",
                                                 "WITH",
                                                 "WITHIN GROUP",
                                                 "WRITETEXT",
                                                 "ABSOLUTE",
                                                 "ACTION",
                                                 "ADA",
                                                 "ALLOCATE",
                                                 "ARE",
                                                 "ASSERTION",
                                                 "AT",
                                                 "AVG",
                                                 "BIT",
                                                 "BIT_LENGTH",
                                                 "BOTH",
                                                 "CASCADED",
                                                 "CAST",
                                                 "CATALOG",
                                                 "CHAR",
                                                 "CHAR_LENGTH",
                                                 "CHARACTER",
                                                 "CHARACTER_LENGTH",
                                                 "COLLATION",
                                                 "CONNECT",
                                                 "CONNECTION",
                                                 "CONSTRAINTS",
                                                 "CORRESPONDING",
                                                 "COUNT",
                                                 "DATE",
                                                 "DAY",
                                                 "DEC",
                                                 "DECIMAL",
                                                 "DEFERRABLE",
                                                 "DEFERRED",
                                                 "DESCRIBE",
                                                 "DESCRIPTOR",
                                                 "DIAGNOSTICS",
                                                 "DISCONNECT",
                                                 "DOMAIN",
                                                 "END-EXEC",
                                                 "EXCEPTION",
                                                 "EXTRACT",
                                                 "FALSE",
                                                 "FIRST",
                                                 "FLOAT",
                                                 "FORTRAN",
                                                 "FOUND",
                                                 "GET",
                                                 "GLOBAL",
                                                 "GO",
                                                 "HOUR",
                                                 "IMMEDIATE",
                                                 "INCLUDE",
                                                 "INDICATOR",
                                                 "INITIALLY",
                                                 "INPUT",
                                                 "INSENSITIVE",
                                                 "INT",
                                                 "INTEGER",
                                                 "INTERVAL",
                                                 "ISOLATION",
                                                 "LANGUAGE",
                                                 "LAST",
                                                 "LEADING",
                                                 "LEVEL",
                                                 "LOCAL",
                                                 "LOWER",
                                                 "MATCH",
                                                 "MAX",
                                                 "MIN",
                                                 "MINUTE",
                                                 "MODULE",
                                                 "MONTH",
                                                 "NAMES",
                                                 "NATURAL",
                                                 "NCHAR",
                                                 "NEXT",
                                                 "NO",
                                                 "NONE",
                                                 "NUMERIC",
                                                 "OCTET_LENGTH",
                                                 "ONLY",
                                                 "OUTPUT",
                                                 "OVERLAPS",
                                                 "PAD",
                                                 "PARTIAL",
                                                 "PASCAL",
                                                 "POSITION",
                                                 "PREPARE",
                                                 "PRESERVE",
                                                 "PRIOR",
                                                 "PRIVILEGES",
                                                 "REAL",
                                                 "RELATIVE",
                                                 "ROWS",
                                                 "SCROLL",
                                                 "SECOND",
                                                 "SECTION",
                                                 "SESSION",
                                                 "SIZE",
                                                 "SMALLINT",
                                                 "SPACE",
                                                 "SQL",
                                                 "SQLCA",
                                                 "SQLCODE",
                                                 "SQLERROR",
                                                 "SQLSTATE",
                                                 "SQLWARNING",
                                                 "SUBSTRING",
                                                 "SUM",
                                                 "TEMPORARY",
                                                 "TIME",
                                                 "TIMESTAMP",
                                                 "TIMEZONE_HOUR",
                                                 "TIMEZONE_MINUTE",
                                                 "TRAILING",
                                                 "TRANSLATE",
                                                 "TRANSLATION",
                                                 "TRIM",
                                                 "TRUE",
                                                 "UNKNOWN",
                                                 "UPPER",
                                                 "USAGE",
                                                 "USING",
                                                 "VALUE",
                                                 "VARCHAR",
                                                 "WHENEVER",
                                                 "WORK",
                                                 "WRITE",
                                                 "YEAR",
                                                 "ZONE",
                                                 "ADMIN",
                                                 "AFTER",
                                                 "AGGREGATE",
                                                 "ALIAS",
                                                 "ARRAY",
                                                 "ASENSITIVE",
                                                 "ASYMMETRIC",
                                                 "ATOMIC",
                                                 "BEFORE",
                                                 "BINARY",
                                                 "BLOB",
                                                 "BOOLEAN",
                                                 "BREADTH",
                                                 "CALL",
                                                 "CALLED",
                                                 "CARDINALITY",
                                                 "CLASS",
                                                 "CLOB",
                                                 "COLLECT",
                                                 "COMPLETION",
                                                 "CONDITION",
                                                 "CONSTRUCTOR",
                                                 "CORR",
                                                 "COVAR_POP",
                                                 "COVAR_SAMP",
                                                 "CUBE",
                                                 "CUME_DIST",
                                                 "CURRENT_CATALOG",
                                                 "CURRENT_DEFAULT_TRANSFORM_GROUP",
                                                 "CURRENT_PATH",
                                                 "CURRENT_ROLE",
                                                 "CURRENT_SCHEMA",
                                                 "CURRENT_TRANSFORM_GROUP_FOR_TYPE",
                                                 "CYCLE",
                                                 "DATA",
                                                 "DEPTH",
                                                 "DEREF",
                                                 "DESTROY",
                                                 "DESTRUCTOR",
                                                 "DETERMINISTIC",
                                                 "DICTIONARY",
                                                 "DYNAMIC",
                                                 "EACH",
                                                 "ELEMENT",
                                                 "EQUALS",
                                                 "EVERY",
                                                 "FILTER",
                                                 "FREE",
                                                 "FULLTEXTTABLE",
                                                 "FUSION",
                                                 "GENERAL",
                                                 "GROUPING",
                                                 "HOLD",
                                                 "HOST",
                                                 "IGNORE",
                                                 "INITIALIZE",
                                                 "INOUT",
                                                 "INTERSECTION",
                                                 "ITERATE",
                                                 "LARGE",
                                                 "LATERAL",
                                                 "LESS",
                                                 "LIKE_REGEX",
                                                 "LIMIT",
                                                 "LN",
                                                 "LOCALTIME",
                                                 "LOCALTIMESTAMP",
                                                 "LOCATOR",
                                                 "MAP",
                                                 "MEMBER",
                                                 "METHOD",
                                                 "MOD",
                                                 "MODIFIES",
                                                 "MODIFY",
                                                 "MULTISET",
                                                 "NCLOB",
                                                 "NEW",
                                                 "NORMALIZE",
                                                 "OBJECT",
                                                 "OCCURRENCES_REGEX",
                                                 "OLD",
                                                 "OPERATION",
                                                 "ORDINALITY",
                                                 "OUT",
                                                 "OVERLAY",
                                                 "PARAMETER",
                                                 "PARAMETERS",
                                                 "PARTITION",
                                                 "PATH",
                                                 "POSTFIX",
                                                 "PREFIX",
                                                 "PREORDER",
                                                 "PERCENT_RANK",
                                                 "PERCENTILE_CONT",
                                                 "PERCENTILE_DISC",
                                                 "POSITION_REGEX",
                                                 "RANGE",
                                                 "READS",
                                                 "RECURSIVE",
                                                 "REF",
                                                 "REFERENCING",
                                                 "REGR_AVGX",
                                                 "REGR_AVGY",
                                                 "REGR_COUNT",
                                                 "REGR_INTERCEPT",
                                                 "REGR_R2",
                                                 "REGR_SLOPE",
                                                 "REGR_SXX",
                                                 "REGR_SXY",
                                                 "REGR_SYY",
                                                 "RELEASE",
                                                 "RESULT",
                                                 "RETURNS",
                                                 "ROLE",
                                                 "ROLLUP",
                                                 "ROUTINE",
                                                 "ROW",
                                                 "SAVEPOINT",
                                                 "SCOPE",
                                                 "SEARCH",
                                                 "SENSITIVE",
                                                 "SEQUENCE",
                                                 "SETS",
                                                 "SIMILAR",
                                                 "SPECIFIC",
                                                 "SPECIFICTYPE",
                                                 "SQLEXCEPTION",
                                                 "START",
                                                 "STATE",
                                                 "STATEMENT",
                                                 "STATIC",
                                                 "STDDEV_POP",
                                                 "STDDEV_SAMP",
                                                 "STRUCTURE",
                                                 "SUBMULTISET",
                                                 "SUBSTRING_REGEX",
                                                 "SYMMETRIC",
                                                 "SYSTEM",
                                                 "TERMINATE",
                                                 "THAN",
                                                 "TRANSLATE_REGEX",
                                                 "TREAT",
                                                 "UESCAPE",
                                                 "UNDER",
                                                 "UNNEST",
                                                 "VAR_POP",
                                                 "VAR_SAMP",
                                                 "VARIABLE",
                                                 "WIDTH_BUCKET",
                                                 "WITHOUT",
                                                 "WINDOW",
                                                 "WITHIN",
                                                 "XMLAGG",
                                                 "XMLATTRIBUTES",
                                                 "XMLBINARY",
                                                 "XMLCAST",
                                                 "XMLCOMMENT",
                                                 "XMLCONCAT",
                                                 "XMLDOCUMENT",
                                                 "XMLELEMENT",
                                                 "XMLEXISTS",
                                                 "XMLFOREST",
                                                 "XMLITERATE",
                                                 "XMLNAMESPACES",
                                                 "XMLPARSE",
                                                 "XMLPI",
                                                 "XMLQUERY",
                                                 "XMLSERIALIZE",
                                                 "XMLTABLE",
                                                 "XMLTEXT",
                                                 "XMLVALIDATE"}

End Module
```

The purpose of the class is to handle the actual creation, removal and changing of user accounts in the database.

Each of the main methods takes a blank `SqlCommand` with `Connection` (and potentially `Transaction`) already set by the calling code.

Before `CreateUser` or `RenameUser` is called, it is expected that the caller has already called `ValidateUserName` and has insured that no user by that name already exists.

`IllegalCharacters` was filled with any special character I could think of that I wouldn't think would be sensibly used in a username. `ReservedNames` was built from the MSDN page on [Reserved Keywords](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) as well as [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/173148/184962) from a question on the dba stack exchange.

## What I'm Worrying About & What I'm Not

The only way I could find to manage these users was by using dynamic SQL, so naturally I'm pretty concerned about SQL injection. I run each username and password through `QUOTENAME` to try and mitigate that, and I'm hoping that that, combined with `ValidateUserName` should be enough, but if anyone can think of a hole in this, let me know. Also, if anyone can tell me a way to do this without having to resort to dynamic SQL, I'm all ears.

I'm not particularly worried about the fact that I'm passing the passwords around in memory in plain text. The password for the currently logged in user (when not using Windows authentication) is stored as a `SecureString`, but since I need plain text passwords eventually to construct the dynamic SQL, I kept all of this component plain text. If anyone can tell me a way to create these users using `SecureString`, or using some other more-secure method, I'd be happy to hear it.

For this particular question, I'm also not overly-worried about the permissions that these users obviously need to have within the database itself in order to be able to create/drop/rename other users. I'll hear you out- particularly if you have a usable suggestion- but I'm not very concerned at the moment.

Comment: This is doing it the hard way. Instead, create (one or more) Active Directory Groups, and give the groups permission to the database and database objects. Then, new users just have to be added to the group(s), and terminated users removed from the group(s). Typically, you could have a read-only AD group, an application admin group, maybe a power user group, but that's all dependent upon the roles within the app.

Comment: @HardCode That assumes that you have an active directory to begin with. Plus it would require a separate interface for managing users outside of the application (the AD admin screen). That is unless  I make a management interface inside the app, in which case it's the same as what I already have except instead of calling SQL to create/manage users I would be calling the Active Directory to do the same.

Comment: Yes. You stated Windows logins, and of course user access would be managed by Active Directory. But you wouldn't need to add *user* domain accounts to SQL Server, only the static groups.

Comment: @HardCode Right, I see what your saying. Normally I do manage SQL access by using an Active Directory with a group, and this app can do that. But there are some environments (poorly managed workgroups) where I can't take advantage of an AD. That's what the the code in this question is for: providing a method of authentication that doesn't reply on Windows.